# How to Repeat Images on RDLC Report

Tags: image, ssrs-2008, report, rdlc

Essentially I'm trying to repeat an image (black X) on top of another image (grid). There can be 0 or more black X's displayed.

What I'm thinking of doing is binding a datasource to the report in which it supplies the top and left values of each X so I can place them in the correct box.

What report item would be appropriate for my purpose? Does any one have a link to a similar issue that I can use as a reference.

Thanks!

[image]

**EDIT:**

I decided to use a list to repeat the X image, and so far it's working except that the images is rendered on a different row each time.

Now my question has changed to, how can I have the items in a list repeat on the same row?

Thanks

Comment: Interesting, how would I go on about this?

Comment: Can you show your dataset and desired output?